# Login not working with login form

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 4.
I had my configuration like:

```java
http
    .requiresChannel()
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("<URLS>").hasAnyAuthority(CUSTOMER.toUpperCase(), BRANCH.toUpperCase())
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
```

with this configuration, I am able to access Spring's login URL:

```
localhost:9080/contextpath/login?username=BNH123456&password=pass
```

But now when I use a login form configuration as following:

```java
http
    .requiresChannel()
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("<URLS>").hasAnyAuthority(CUSTOMER.toUpperCase(), BRANCH.toUpperCase())
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage(journey.equalsIgnoreCase("customer") ? "/" : "/#!/login")
```

I am unable to access the Spring's login URL. It says:

> Error 404.

Is it necessary to define a custom controller when I define login form?

I want to use my custom login form but it uses Spring's login URL. (If I hit a post request for login using Postman, it should authenticate.)

Can anyone please guide.

Comment: `#` will not be received on the server those are client side anchors and will not be send to the server.

Comment: We are using angular on frontend and we have 2 types of journeys. for customer journey my start page is "/" but for staff journey my start page is "/#!/login". angular sends the username and password to backend for validation. when I did not put "loginform" it worked fine, but when I added, the same url

localhost:9080/contextpath/login?username=BNH123456&password=pass

stopped working.

Comment: Why should it be different... Just call the same entry point. And no your startpage isn't `/#!/login` it still is `/`. Angular parses the `#!/login` part.

Comment: @M.Deinum it is redirecting well but the spring's login url stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the URL of the login page, you also change the URL for login, see [`FormLoginConfigurer#loginPage`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/FormLoginConfigurer.html#loginPage-java.lang.String-):

> **Impact on other defaults**
>
> Updating this value, also impacts a number of other default values. For example, the following are the default values when only formLogin() was specified.
>
> - /login GET - the login form
> - /login POST - process the credentials and if valid authenticate the user
> - /login?error GET - redirect here for failed authentication attempts
> - /login?logout GET - redirect here after successfully logging out
>
> If "/authenticate" was passed to this method it update the defaults as shown below:
>
> - /authenticate GET - the login form
> - /authenticate POST - process the credentials and if valid authenticate the user
> - /authenticate?error GET - redirect here for failed authentication attempts
> - /authenticate?logout GET - redirect here after successfully logging out

There are two solutions:

- change the URL in your custom form (to `/`) or
- change the processing URL in your Spring Security configuration (to `/login`), see [`AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer#loginProcessingUrl`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.html#loginProcessingUrl-java.lang.String-)